# Printing high resolution with temporary Bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I want to print labels. If I draw to the printing contexts Graphics object, it works without problems. But if I use a temporary Bitmap all the drawn text is pixelated. I recognized that the resolution of the temp Bitmap and the printing Graphics object are different (96 dpi vs. 600 dpi). So I change the Bitmaps resolution to match the printing resolution. So all the drawn text is too big.

I need the temporary Bitmap to rotate the image before printing.

How to get this Bitmap correctly printed?

**Pixalated code:** (looks bad but has the temporary bitmap)

```
    // print event handler
    private void printPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        // size of the page
        Size s = Form1.getPixelFromCM(Properties.Settings.Default.LabelSize);
        // temporary bitmap object
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        // draw text 
        labels[printLabelsIndex].PrintLabel(g);
        // draw the bitmap to the page
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
    }
```

This code produces this print:

[image]

**High resolution code:** (looks good but I need the temporary bitmap!)

```
    // print event handler
    private void printPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        // draw text directly to print context
        labels[printLabelsIndex].PrintLabel(ev.Graphics);
    }
```

This code produces this print:

[image]

Comment: You have to make the bitmap 6 times larger.  And draw it 6 times smaller.  And not forget to use Graphics.Clear() to set its background color, anti-aliasing cannot work correctly if you forget.  Just do this the Right Way, use the Graphics.Transform property to rotate output.  The Matrix.RotateAt() method is a nice convenience method.

Comment: Graphics.Clear() was a good point. AA does work now. But it is still pixelated because of wrong resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good thing that `Graphics.DrawImage` honors the Bitmap's  resolution, although it sometimes leads to confusion, when  one assumes that all pieces of the puzzle have the same resolution..

Here you need to set the resolution of the temporary Bitmap explicitly or else if simply inherits the screen resolution..:

```
bmp.SetResolution(600,600)
```

Of course now the Labels' Size will probably  not be large enough..

Also note a problem with terminology: Resolution may mean size i.e. pixels or printer dots but really ought to mean density i.e. `dpi` or ' dots per inch' .

You want to bring up the size **and** also the `dpi`!

Comment: But the printing Graphics doesn't have higher pixel resolution. Why do I need it for the Bitmap object? This makes drawing more complicated as it differs.

Comment: Well, that is how it is. The other DrawXXX methods all draw on a per pixel coordinate system, butDrawImage uses the dpi of the bitmap. Unless you prevent that by using the overload with two rectangles; but blowing up a bitmap that is too small obviously won't help.. - Not knowing the `labels[printLabelsIndex].PrintLabel(g);` class/method we can't do more than give general advice..

Comment: PrintLabel() does generate text which is drawn by g.DrawString(). The positions are all pixels. So it won't work with both ways without modification. I was hoping it is possible with one method to draw things. printLabel() should draw on every Graphics object the same way as all is for printing in the end.

Comment: With some care you should be able to get away with setting the scaing without calulating the coordinates and sizes. Note that in addition to the bitmap the Graphics object also can be scaled..